in Kunen set theory forcing part, how to show this set is function?
I read Kunen's set theory pp.192-3.
in this page, example said that p forces certain set is function;

...

but I don't understand how to first set can be function; because  |P is set of functions, so it seems that there are distinct function x, y in |P s.t. x(0)= 0, y(0)=0, but x contains y. then it seems that this situation not contradict with _G is function, because G is filter, so if y is in G then we can find extension function of y, say x, then we can preserve f_G is function while x, y are in G.
so how to show  is force from 1(this is greatest element in |P)?

What is your question? Do you ask how to show if $1$ forces $\Phi$ is a function from $\check{\omega}$ to $\check{2}$, or $1$ forces $\Phi=\bigcup\Gamma$?

Also, your question heavily depends on the choice of $\mathbb{P}$. I guess $\mathbb{P}$ is $\operatorname{Fn}(\omega,2)$, is it correct?

@Hanul Jeon I asked how to show p forces Φ is function. When prove this, must show that Φ((x,y)')=z, Φ((x,y)')=u then z=u. But i cant how to show that

@Hanul Jeon because it seems that large P can have distinct function,say p and q s.t. p(n)=m=q(n). Then Φ((m,n)') have values p and q, so not a function. I cant find where i have misunderstood

You should check spaceisdarkgreen's answer. Also, I recommend you use Grammarly or ChatGPT to clarify your English. Many people (including me) use Broken English on this website, and I know using an unfamiliar language to write unfamiliar questions is frustratingly hard, but sometimes bad English hinders the true intention of your question.

Regarding your comment (as far as I understand) different $p$ may force different statements; For example, if $p(0)=0$ and $q(0)=1$, then $p\Vdash \Phi(\check{0})=\check{0}$ and $q\Vdash \Phi(\check{0})=\check{1}$. There is no contradiction here since $p$ and $q$ are incompatible, so you cannot combine these two into one.

spaceisdarkgreen gave a nice semantic proof for the forcibility of the statement "$\Phi$ is a function from $\check{\omega}$ to $\check{2}$. You may prove it syntactically, albeit it is a bit harder. (I should acknowledge that I have not syntactically proven it by hand.) BTW if you have a Discord account feel free to get in touch with me.

$G$ being a filter doesn't merely mean there's no contradiction, it implies that $\Phi_G$ is a function (though not necessarily total on $\omega)$. This is because all elements of a filter $G$ are compatible. So if $p,q\in G$ and $n\in \operatorname{dom}(p)\cap \operatorname{dom}(q),$ then $p(n)=q(n).$ So if $(n,m),(n,m')\in \Phi_G,$ then $m=m'.$
In order to get that $\Phi_G$ is a total function $\omega\to 2,$ we need that $G$ is generic. It follows from the fact that for every $n\in \omega,$ $\{p\in P: n\in \operatorname{dom}(p)\}$ is dense, and therefore $\exists p\in G$ such that $n\in \operatorname{dom}(p)$ and we have $n\in\operatorname{dom}(\Phi_G).$
Since $\Phi_G$ is a function $\omega\to 2$ for every generic filter $G$ (equivalently for every generic filter $G$ containing $1$) we have $1\Vdash\mbox{$\Phi$ is a function $\check\omega\to \check 2.$}$
